# Kotor Montenegro restaurants

Tags: restaurants, montenegro

I'm looking for good reputation and not to expensive (max. 20 Euro for two persons for a dinner) restaurants (Fish/Meat + French Fries or something like that maybe pizza?) in Montenegro, Kotor or nearest area. If you have any addresses this will be very helpful.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Please review the [Help page](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help) because your question as it stands is unanswerable.  1.  What's cheap?  2. What's good?  3.  What kind of restaurant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Grispolis" near Bigova is about a 20 Minute drive from Kotor. Its off the main street but fits into your pricepoint, has direct access to the sea and good food.

Link to the restaurant at google: https://plus.google.com/102648994141906332875/about?rfmt=s&hl=en

Comment: Also a good restaurant I found here (it's placed on a lake):
https://www.google.pl/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d888!2d19.0399614!3d42.3513499!2m1!1e3&fid=7
It's approx 1km far than "Restaurant Stari Most"

Comment: Marcos, the restaurant you mentioned is at least a 1 hour drive from Kotor.